# Git workflow for cloned websites

Tags: git

I have been working on a website - `Project B` since few days. Now, the client wants me to create a clone of `Project B` called `Project C`.

However, it's not a complete clone. There are obvious changes in design, color schemes and also in some sections of the website.

How do I manage these two projects effectively by spending as less time as possible on git?

Here's my idea of workflow:

Setup:

1. I create a parent project called `Project A` and copy over `Project B` to `Project A`.
2. I remove the stuff that's specific to `Project B` and do a `git init` in `Project A`.
3. I fetch `Project A` into `Project C` and start working on the changes specific to `Project C`.

How do I manage all this effectively? Is there a better technique to manage such projects with git?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Branch based

Why not use branches for this you can get everything project specific out of the way `git init` a new repository `git commit` everything. Then `git checkout -b ProjectB` get all project specific files in then `git commit` that too after that you can `git checkout -b ProjectC master`. This sequance will create 2 branches based of *master* called *ProjectB* & *ProjectC*.

```
       [com2]<-ProjectB
      /
[com1]<-master
      \
       [com3]<-ProjectC
```

I would highly prefer the one above but the workflow you suggested is fine too. Repository based workflow would keep all the data seperate that would be much more useful if you had different clients. Well I would use the branch approach either way.

Comment: +1 for branches. When your final version (of A or B) is ready, tag it so (`0.1-alpha` or whatever) and `git archive` the tree to a tarball that you can deploy.